# Efficiently build a Polars DataFrame row by row in Rust

Tags: rust, rayon, rust-polars

I would like to create a large Polars `DataFrame` using Rust, building it up row by row using data scraped from web pages. What is an efficient way to do this?

It looks like the `DataFrame` should be created from a `Vec` of `Series` rather than adding rows to an empty DataFrame. However, how should a `Series` be built up efficiently? I could create a `Vec` and then create a `Series` from the `Vec`, but that sounds like it will end up copying all elements. Is there a way to build up a `Series` element-by-element, and then build a `DataFrame` from those?

I will actually be building up several DataFrames in parallel using Rayon, then combining them, but it looks like vstack does what I want there. It's the creation of the individual DataFrames that I can't find out how to do efficiently.

I did look at the source of the CSV parser but that is very complicated, and probably highly optimised, but is there a simple approach that is still reasonably efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
pub fn from_vec(
    name: &str,
    v: Vec<<T as PolarsNumericType>::Native, Global>
) -> ChunkedArray<T>
```

> Create a new ChunkedArray by taking ownership of the Vec. This operation is zero copy.

[here](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#method.from_vec) is the link. You can then call `into_series` on it.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this will work for numeric types, but not strings. However, your answer pointed me in the direction to find `Utf8ChunkedBuilder` which looks like it can.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, if perhaps not the most performant, answer is to just maintain a map of vectors and turn them into the series that get fed to a DataFrame all at once.

```rust
let columns = BTreeMap::new();
for datum in get_data_from_web() {
    // For simplicity suppose datum is itself a BTreeMap
    // (More likely it's a serde_json::Value)
    // It's assumed that every datum has the same keys; if not, the 
    // Vecs won't have the same length
    // It's also assumed that the values of datum are all of the same known type

    for (k, v) in datum {
        columns.entry(k).or_insert(vec![]).push(v);
    }
}

let df = DataFrame::new(
    columns.into_iter()
        .map(|(name, values)| Series::new(name, values))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    ).unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks. That is easy to understand but I’d like to minimise copying. The ChunkedArray method proposed by Jakub looks good in that respect for numeric data and Utf8ChunkedBuilder looks good for strings.